# Ellipse in "ein paar vegetarische"

Tags: usage

Aus einem Roman<sup>1</sup>:

> "Ich glaube schon", sagte ich. "Ich muss um zehn zu Hause sein. Und ich, also, ich esse kein Fleisch."
>
> "Kein Problem. Wir machen **ein paar vegetarische**", sagte sie.

Man kann raten, dass sich die zweite Person auf ein paar vegetarische **Gerichte** oder **Speisen** bezieht. Keines der beiden Worte kommt jedoch im Gespräch vor. Ist es in der Umgangssprache üblich, das Nomen wegzulassen, wenn es sich vom Kontext gut raten lässt, aber nicht schon vorher vorkommt?

---

<sup>1</sup> John Green: Das Schicksal ist ein mieser Verräter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In diesem Fall ist der Kontext durchaus vorhanden, allerdings eine Seite zuvor in der Beschreibung der Szene:

> Seine Eltern standen in der Küche und machten Enchiladas.

Die Sprecherin (die Mutter) muss das Gericht nicht nennen, da die Zuhörerin (Hazel) laut Szenenbeschreibung sehen kann, wovon sie spricht, also ist die Auslassung ok.

Vom Leser wird erwartet, dass er noch weiß, was eine Seite zuvor erklärt wurde.

Comment: Cool. Kanntest du das Buch? Wie hast du diese Stelle gefunden? Ich bin beim Versuch, das im Internet zu recherchieren, gescheitert.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Zitat markiert, Rechtsklick, "Search Google for ...". Dann schlug Google *gestern* "automatisch" das Buch bei Google Books vor, heute musste ich dazu extra über mehr -> Bücher gehen. Ich liebe es, wenn der Suchalgorithmus schlauer sein will, als ich. Als ich heute nur nach der zweiten Zeile gegoogelt habe, kanm auch Google Books als dritter Treffer.

Answer (score 2):

Man sagt so etwas nicht, wenn nicht klar ist, worauf sich das „vegetarische“ bezieht. In diesem Fall bezieht es sich auf [Enchiladas](https://books.google.de/books?id=QiJQAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT32&ots=ebn932YhgA&dq=sagte%20ich.%20%22Ich%20muss%20um%20zehn%20zu%20Hause%20sein.%20Und%20ich%2C%20also%2C%20ich%20esse%20kein%20Fleisch.%22%22Kein%20Problem.%20Wir%20machen%20ein%20paar%20vegetarische%22%2C%20sagte%20sie.&pg=PT33#v=onepage&q=sagte%20ich.%20%22Ich%20muss%20um%20zehn%20zu%20Hause%20sein.%20Und%20ich,%20also,%20ich%20esse%20kein%20Fleisch.%22%22Kein%20Problem.%20Wir%20machen%20ein%20paar%20vegetarische%22,%20sagte%20sie.&f=false).

Comment: Auch wenn ich mir denken kann, dass du den Originaltext gefunden hast und dort auf die Enchiladas gestoßen bist, wäre ein bisschen expliziterer Kontext doch nicht schlecht gewesen. Nicht, dass noch zukünftige Besucher auf den Gedanken kommen: "Wenn im Deutschen das Substantiv ausgelassen wird, sind grundsätzlich Enchiladas gemeint."

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, das hier aber auch immer alle so ernsthaft sind!  :)